# Python Вывод ошибки и stacktrace в консоль

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, отладка

Кау вывести в консоль текст ошибки и stacktrace так, как это делается при необработанном исключении:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file", line 67, in <module>
    M.logoutv()
  File "file", line 260, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("Unknown IMAP4 command: '%s'" % attr)
AttributeError: Unknown IMAP4 command: 'logoutv'
```

хочу поймать в `try:`
обработать в `except Exception as err:`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Получить текст трассы стека можно через функцию [traceback.format_exc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exc):

```
import traceback

try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    print('Ошибка:\n', traceback.format_exc())
```

Answer (score 5):

Следуя вашим словам, например:

```
try:
    do_something()
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
    do_something_else()
```

Comment: Насколько я помню, так выведет только тип исключения, но не трейсбэк.

Comment: [Скриншот](http://i.imgur.com/te62IZd.png)

Comment: @insolor точно, про трейсбэк я просто не заметил